# How to insert Code to Word and save as MD - writage plugin drops code formatting

Tags: ms-word, markdown

How does one format code snippets (in JavaScript, Java, C#, Etc...) in Word so they keep the formatting on save as MD with Writage plugin (or any other way)?

I copy form VS Code to Word, and it looks fine.
What I would like to do is add line numbering in the code and shading of lines, and most importantly keep the original font / color format. Here is my word version after pasting code from VS Code:

[image: Code in Word]

and here is the MD file that is generated with Writage: (preview on the right)... the comments are not green, nor is func blue, font is different,  etc
[image: Preview of MD via Writage plugin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add three backqoute/backtick (```) at the beginning and at the end of your code snippet along with the language name.

[image: Input image]

Preview:

[image: Output image]

For more details:

- [Markdown:Code-and-Syntax-Highlighting](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code-and-syntax-highlighting)
- [Languages-supported-by-github-flavored-markdown](http://www.rubycoloredglasses.com/2013/04/languages-supported-by-github-flavored-markdown/)

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To format the code in Word, you can try the add-in "Easy Code Formatter".
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-US/product/office/WA104382008?tab=Overview
[image]